# Make Install gives an error after properly cleaned and readied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I have been working on a project that requires me to use make clean, make ready, then make install to get files to run a simulation. I got make clean and make ready to work on the same area but as soon as I try to run a make install it won't work and gives this error:

ifort -w  -O -tpp7  -c main.f

make: ifort: Command not found

make: *** [makefile:640: main.o] Error 127

this makes no sense to me as I don't have a Linux system and I'm running on a windows system with WSL and Ubuntu. There is a makefile if that is helpful but I don't really know what to look for in that file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have the `ifort` Fortran compiler installed, or it's not in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I installed fortran and now I am unsure how to add it to the path, would you know how?

Comment: Put `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/where/fortran/installed` in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Note, that `PATH` contains _directories_ where programs are looked for.  You don't put the programs themselves there.  So find the directory containing the `ifort` program and add that directory to your `PATH`.

Comment: I typed in the path command into ubuntu, it just sent me to a newline and didn't give any confirmation on whether it worked. Does the .bashrc refer to something other than the command line? Also the directory is in Program Files x86 which I typed as programfilesx86 when I set the path. Should I type this a diffeernt way?